# Convert DEM elevation points from centimeters to meters

Tags: postgis, dem, convert, performance, elevation

I would like to convert a large DEM stored in PostGIS which contains elevation values in centimeters to elevation in meters.

I found an easy way by updating each point like this:

```
UPDATE mydem a
SET rast = ST_SetValue(rast, x, y, val / 100)
FROM (SELECT rid, x, y, val FROM (SELECT rid, (ST_PixelAsPoints(rast)).* FROM mydem) t) r
WHERE a.rid = r.rid;
```

It works but very slowly, much too slow to process large tables. Is there is any faster way to achieve this ?

Comment: Use https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_MapAlgebra.html and specify your callback function to do the division (or multiply by 0.01).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BradHards comment is good, but it can be even simpler with the [MapAlgebraExpression](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_MapAlgebra_expr.html) variant. For these simple uses-cases you don't need to add a callback function but you can just add an expression to the function. In your case:

```
UPDATE mydem a
SET rast =
    ST_MapAlgebra(rast, 1, NULL, '[rast.val] / 100')
FROM foo
```

Comment: Great, it works perfectly!